# Adicionar classe com JQuery ao abrir a página

Tags: jquery, laravel

Olá. Estou tentando fazer uma central de monitoramento para os computadores da rede.

Cada div irá fazer o ping em um IP e em seguida retorna ON ou OFF.

Em seguida, com JQuery, atribuo o valor da variável do PHP e, caso esteja ON irá adicionar a classe FUNDO-VERDE, se estiver off, a classe FUNDO-VERMELHO.

Porém, o meu código JQuery não está funcionando, o fundo da div não está ficando com a cor correta. Qual o problema com o JQuery?

Uma outra dúvida é como fazer o reload APENAS das divs, sem recarregar a página toda?

```css
.fundo-verde{
 color:#155724;
 background-color:#d4edda;
 border-color:#c3e6cb;
 position:relative;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 border-radius:.25rem}
 

.fundo-vermelho{
 color:#721c24;
 background-color:#f8d7da;
 border-color:#f5c6cb;
 position:relative;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 border-radius:.25rem}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 text-center font-weight-bold border border-light" id="meupc">

      PC MONITORADO 1
            
      <p><?php exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 " . "192.168.0.75", $output, $result);

     if ($result == 0) {
     echo "ON";
     } else {
     echo "OFF";
     } ?>

      </p>
          
      <script type="text/javascript">
     var resultado = <?=$result?>;
     $(document).ready(function(){
      if (resultado==0){
        $('#meupc').addClass('fundo-verde');}
      else {
        $('#meupc').addClass('fundo-vermelho');}}); 
      </script>
              
    </div>
```

Comment: Fazer reload, será preciso o uso do jquery, com o método `.load()`

Comment: Essa variável `$result` retorna algo diferente de zero ? Fiz uns teste e sempre retorna zero, até mesmo em ips sem latência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso renomeando a classe para cada tipo de status.

```
.on{
    color:#155724;
    background-color:#d4edda;
    border-color:#c3e6cb;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius:.25rem}


.off{
    color:#721c24;
    background-color:#f8d7da;
    border-color:#f5c6cb;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius:.25rem}
```

```
<div class="col-3 text-center font-weight-bold border border-light <?php echo $result == 0 ? 'on' : 'off' ?>" id="meupc">
    PC MONITORADO 1
    <p>
    <?php
        if ($result == 0) {
            echo "ON";
        } else {
            echo "OFF";
        } ?>
    </p>    
</div>
```